# Should I specify 'virtual' again when I override a C++ function?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

When I override a virtual function:

```
class Geoff
{
 public:
  virtual int getArea() { return 0; }
}
```

Should I specify 'virtual' again when I override it? Does it make any difference? I know both ways seem to work fine, just wondering if there's more to it than that.

```
class George : public Geoff
{
 public:
  virtual int getArea() { return x*y; }
}
```

Comment: It's not a dupe, but it's certainly related.

Comment: @一二三: that's a poor candidate for a duplicate, as it actually asks if you can somehow "replace" a function ***without*** using the virtual keyword (good answers explain the difference between hiding and virtual dispatch).

Comment: @TonyD - it's a race you see, to be the first person to mangle the question by editing it into something it's not, or having the question shutdown altogether. ;-P

Comment: If it's closed as a duplicate of that questions, I'll just reopen it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use C++11, you should use [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) instead, which both documents that you're overriding a virtual function and checks that a matching virtual function exists in a base for overriding.

```
int getArea() override { return x*y; }
```

In C++03 it's a stylistic choice - put `virtual` in if you feel it adds documentation value.

Comment: You can also use `final` to prevent further overrides, and that lets the compiler more easily devirtualise calls to that member function.

Comment: I think if you know that GEORGE will be extended, then put virtual with it. For understanding purpose.

Comment: @Al-mo I'm sorry, but that's bad advice. The "override" is more than clear enough in showing that the method is virtual.

Comment: I am sorry @Steven Sudit, that was intended for the code provided in the question. Not this answer.

Answer (score 7):

No, use *override*. (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override)

It has the advantage of failing if the method is not virtual in the parent.

*edit*

As Mark pointed out, it also fails if the signature doesn't match, whereas virtual would silently "succeed". The scare quotes are because a mismatched signature would hide the shadowed method in the base and make a new virtual method that's unrelated.

Comment: And it also checks if the overriding method has a compatible signature with the method being overridden (that it actually overrides the method, yes).

Comment: @MarkGarcia That's true, and a good point, because you wouldn't want to accidentally overload when trying to override.

Comment: Thanks, override still generates a warning for me in VS2010 so I'll have to look into that one with our architects.

Comment: @DerfSkren VS2010 is not a great C++ compiler, but it does support override. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41w3sh1c.aspx

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be trying to put override in the front, not at the end. Look at the examples I linked to above and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: No it's considered a 'non-standard extension' by the VS2010 compiler: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173703%28v=vs.100%29.aspx